# Loop through php array and insert key=>value at specified position

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
[
    {"key": 1, "title": "Animalia", "expanded": true, "folder": true, "children": [
        {"key": 2, "title": "Chordate", "folder": true, "children": [
            {"key": 3, "title": "Mammal", "children": [
                {"key": 4, "title": "Primate", "children": [
                    {"key": 5, "title": "Primate", "children": [
                    ]},
                    {"key": 6, "title": "Carnivora", "children": [
                    ]}
                ]},
                {"key": 7, "title": "Carnivora", "children": [
                    {"key": 8, "title": "Felidae"}
                ]}
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

I want to loop trough the array and when the "key" equals a specified number (let's say 5) I want to insert a "selected": true key=>value

Is there such a possibility?

Comment: First of all, this is not a valid PHP code. Is this a JSON came from javascript?

Comment: yes, it's a json array

Comment: this is not a valid JSON.

Comment: it's a partial copy from my own code, it should be a valid copy other-ways the code should give errors. It's a huge json and there is only a small part of it

Comment: You have to remove comma from `]},`. It should be `]}` then it will be a valid JSON. If you using PHP then first `json_decode($json_string, TRUE)` (second parameter TRUE will return an array) the json string and then loop through the array for the key and insert new keys where you want then you can use `json_encode()` to get back the json string you want.

Comment: After all why you are talking about PHP? Why not to apply whatever you want in javascript?

Comment: All this piece of json is used by PHP classes, so that's why

Comment: @rosuandreimihai just take a look, your JSON is valid and I have the function for you right in my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just make your JSON string to a valid PHP array with $myArray = json_decode(JSONString)

Then you could access the point you want like array_push($myArray[0]["1"], "myValue")

I will need the exact position where you want to add which type of value to give you a better hint... :-)

**Edited with working code**

You have to do a recursive search over your JSON structure, to find your value and to set the Value you need... I wrote you a short php function that does that trick...

As you see, the function takes to params and gives you back the ready php array for further use of it... Just call it like descriped below....

**Usage Example**

```
$myArray = json_decode($myJSON, true);
$myArray = setSelectedForKey($myArray, "6");
echo(json_encode($myArray));
```

**Following the function you need:**

```
function setSelectedForKey($searchArray, $searchKey) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($searchArray); $i++) {
            if ($searchArray[$i]["key"] == $searchKey) {
                $searchArray[$i]["selected"] = true;
            } else {
                if (is_array($searchArray[$i]["children"])) {
                    $searchArray[$i]["children"] = setSelectedForKey($searchArray[$i]["children"], $searchKey);
                }
            }
        }
        return $searchArray;
    }
```

Comment: That is exactly the problem, the position could be anywhere :(

Comment: Ok, give me some time... I will edit my post with the correct code for your problem... I will have to test my code at home tonight, to solve this problem... :-)

Comment: It would be nice if you vote me up for my work :-P :-) have fun with it